# read from file and store into object array "Expression not assignable" c++

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I am trying to read 3 values from a file which look like this example:

```
ADJ09WAD 303 609.
```

`tempString` and `tempInt` are local variables in the function.

```
void read_inventory(item items[], int size) {

  ifstream inStream;
  inStream.open("inventory.txt");
  int ct = 0;  // counter
  int tempInt;
  string tempString;

  if (!inStream.is_open()) {
    cout << "Error, file did not open" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  while (!inStream.eof()) {
    getline(inStream, tempString, ' ');
    items[ct].getid() = tempString;  // accessor to private variables, this one
                                     // is type string and I get no error.

    getline(inStream, tempString, ' ');
    tempInt = atoi(tempString.c_str());  // changing from string to int
    items[ct].getqs() = tempInt;  // I get error "Expression not assignable"

    getline(inStream, tempString, '\n');
    tempInt = atoi(tempString.c_str());
    items[ct].getqr() = tempString;  // same error

    if (ct < size) {
      ct++;
    }
  }
  inStream.close();
};
```

The `item` class is declared as

```
class item {
 private:
  string id;
  int qs;  // quantity sold
  int qr;  // quantity remaining

 public:
  item();
  string getid() const;
  int getqs() const;
  int getqr() const;
  void Print(item I);
};
```

Comment: Not enough information. Show the item class and its methods `getid()`, `getqs()` and `getqr()`.

Comment: This seems to be a variation of your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439127/i-am-trying-to-read-from-a-file-and-store-the-values-into-an-array-of-type-class, and also doesn't contain enough information to reproduce this. Try to write [a complete and minimal example](http://sscce.org) -- this would be helpful for anybody trying to answer and also people coming across this in the future.

Comment: Reading your *previous* question that @BenjaminBannier linked, it seems obvious that you need to learn what a reference is and return references from the non-const getters (like `int&` and `std::string&`). But that is also a bad design smell, I suggest you provide setters as well, even than exposing the internals seems bad design. (After your edit: You have `const` getters, good. Now add setters)

Comment: Your accessor functions are `const` as they should be....now maybe add mutators (i.e. `setid(const string& id)` ).

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: nope, the OP uses the space delimiter explicitly.

Comment: Ok, I made the fixes and I added a cout in the function just to see what it was reading and it showed a bunch of memory allocation it seems..."0x7fff5fbf7c300x7fff5fbf7c300x7fff5" and it goes on.

Comment: @user3598064: Your `get*` functions return strings or ints so I cannot see how that would happen with the code you showed us. Also, why does the **member function** `Print` take a *copy* of some `item` -- it should just access the member variables. The problem might be in how you call it. Either way, get a good book on C++ and review the basics.

Comment: This question made some kind of sense until you corrected the code so that the thing you are asking a question about no longer occurs.  The title is no particularly meaningless. The change has also rendered the answers provided somewhat meaningless.  Questions may be *improved*, but you should not change it to reflect answers given or to ask a different question - post a new question.

Comment: @Clifford I'm sorry I am new to programming and also to this website, but I will avoid doing it in the future.

Comment: @Clifford: I rolled it back.

Comment: Is this resolved now?

Answer (score 3):

> items[ct].getqs() = tempInt; // I get error "Expression not assignable"

Yes, sure, let us take a look at your getter:

int getqs() const;

That means, you are trying to assign the value to an "int" return value. That is not going to fly in C++. What you should probably do is adding a mutator method for it as follows:

```
void setqs(int qs);
```

Having that done, you could fix your code as follows:

```
..
string getid() const;
void setid(const string& id_in) { id = id_in; }
int getqs() const;
void setqs(int qs_in) { qs = qs_in; } 
int getqr() const;
void setqr(int qr_in) { qr = qr_in; }
...

items[ct].setqs(tempInt);
```

Note that you would need to do this similarly for the rest, so your changes would look like this overall:

```
getline(inStream, tempString, ' ');
items[ct].setid(tempString);

getline(inStream, tempString, ' ');
items[ct].setqs(atoi(tempString.c_str()));

getline(inStream, tempString);
items[ct].setqr(atoi(tempString.c_str()));
```

Note that I removed the explicit line end '\n' delimiter for the third since that is the default.

That being said, you should utilize the `std::strtoi` function instead of atoi from C++11 on.

Comment: Great, I fixed it, but I am confused as to how to define the mutator.

Comment: @user3598064: no worries, they are just simple settings. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the following lines:

```
items[ct].getqs() = tempInt;
...
items[ct].getqr() = tempString;
```

The left hand sign is not an assignable expression.  The function itself returns by copy; there is nothing to assign.  They should perhaps return a reference to `item::qs` and item::qr`respectively.  That said to do that gives direct access to`item`'s private members which rather obviates the purpose of private membership.  You would do better to have separate get/set member functions - that conveys a number of advantages - a setter function can have range checking, and provides a break-point location for access to the data - you lose that control when you provide a reference to an objects private members.

The semantics of: `items[ct].getid() = tempString;` is suspect too; I doubt that it is doing what you intended, even if it is syntactically valid.  It *does not* modify the object `items[ct]`, it will modify a temporary to which you have no reference.